# CF memory usage by cf app command

Tags: cloud-foundry

I want to understand memory status reported by cf app command.
e.g. If for my app it returns

```
 state     since                    cpu     memory       disk           details
```

## 0   running   2017-02-11 08:06:39 AM   18.2%   2.2G of 4G   200.3M of 1G

What does this 2.2G means really? Because when I see my application in newrelic it shows like ~1GB being used. I believe actual allocation will also depend on some other parameter (xmx, memory calculatros?)  when application starts.

(It is spring boot application)

Answer (score 3):

When you run `cf app <app-name>`, the output shows the memory and CPU usage that is reported by the Linux Kernel for your container.  Recent versions of CF obtain this using [Guardian](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/guardian) & runc, older versions using [Warden](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/warden).

Conceptually you can think of what it's reporting as the memory usage for all processes running inside the container.  This includes your application processes, but also a couple very small processes put there by the platform (one being the SSH daemon that facilitates `cf ssh`).  If you want to see more about what's running in your container, I would suggest executing `cf ssh` and then looking at `ps aux` or `top`.

In regards to your specific app, the difference that you're seeing is likely due to the fact that it's a Java app.  You need to make sure that you're looking at the full memory usage for the **process** and not just the heap usage.  Heap is only one part of the total memory usage for a Java app, which also includes PermGen (1.7) or Metaspace (1.8), threads, native code, direct memory and other memory used by the JVM itself.

Answer (score 0):

It says that one instance of the app is running. The app was allotted / assigned 4GB of memory out of which (at the time when you ran `cf app`) the app had consumed 2.2 GB of total memory.

If New Relic is reporting close to 1 GB of memory, that could mean there are other things that is taking up the other 1.2 GB of memory.

I would start with looking at the `buildpack` that you are using. Are you using the standard java buildpack or it a custom buildpack that your company created? Does the buildpack add any other agents? Something like AppDynamics (not saying that is the culprit by any means) or something else. Find out that, and identify how much memory those add-ons are consuming.

I would suggest may be doing a `heapdump` of your running instance. You will have to ssh into the container for it. The head dump could be 2.2 GB and the disk assigned to your app is only 1GB, which will pose a problem. There are solutions but that depends on what version of PCF you are running.

Just a quick question, do you by any chance using `nashorn` in your app?

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are using standard buildpack. So, there are no addons then. 
You can try ssh into the app instance container and check out the log files and see if you get any clues on what is running. 

You will have to do `heapdump` to get a good look. 

What version of PCF are you on?